# Captivate 5: Can you call a nested swf inside a swf?

Tags: flash

i'm using captivate 5 to create an elearning project, due to captivates limited animation abilities i created a menu bar in flash and imported it into captivate as an swf.  The menu bar has a glossary listing that whne clicked calls upon another swf which is a glossary.

The problem is that the glossary swf doesnt pop up when the glossary listing is clicked inside of captivate.  The menu bar works perfectly outside of captivate.
the glossary is already made in AS3. So my question is **can you call a nested swf within captivate?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can nest swf's into a Captivate 5 file.  I have successfully tested importing a swf file that was created in AS3.  I have not tested importing swf files created in AS2.

First test your glossary swf in another Flash project that calls your glossary swf (new Flash project that imports your glossary swf file). After debugging or testing your glossary swf, then you can insert it into Captivate 5.

Please note that if you want your imported swf file to interactive with Captivate 5, then you will need to create a widget.  Please refer to Captivate online documentation on how to create a widget using AS3 in Flash or Flex.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I just found another way around that awhile ago but I'll remember this.